# Firebase CLI is not recognizing my project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Why can't anything be easy? I am trying to add push notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging. When I run firebase init I get the following:

[image]

How do I get this to work? I have tried all the solutions I have read here but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI is recognizing your project, but the initialization is failing due to an error with Cloud Storage for Firebase.

Try going to the Storage section within your Firebase Console ([here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage)) and initialize Cloud Storage for Firebase first.

After you've chosen a location for your bucket try running your command again.